# Using import inside lib.d.ts for intellisense in Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I have a set of custom global variables in my JavaScript project and I want to use VSCode intellisense to help me with auto completion like this:

[auto completion for lol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1bSI.png)

After some googling I found a way to use `lib.d.ts` in the same directory as the script.
If `lib.d.ts` doesn't refer other files like this:

```js
// "lib.d.ts" file
class Lol {
    f() : string;
}

declare const lol : Lol;
```

everything works fine.
But when I try to move `Lol` class into a separate file the intellisense refuses to show the `lol` variable in my script file:

```js
// "lol.d.ts" file
export default class Lol {
    f() : string;
}
```

```js
// "lib.d.ts" file
import Lol from "./lol";

declare const lol : Lol;
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: what are the fille names where you put class `Lol` and import the class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found an answer.
Despite scripts (declare style) can pollute global scope and **can't** use `import`, modules can do both.
Instead of using `declare` I switched to `export global` like this:

```js
import Lol from "./lol";

declare global {
    const lol : Lol;
}
```